How to broadcast Stake transaction
I'm trying to write a script to stake SOL from a Fireblocks wallet using the Blockdaemon validator, and I'm stuck at broadcasting the transaction
Here is the process that I followed so far:

Call the stake-intent endpoint on the Blockdaemon API

This returns an unsigned transaction


Using the Fireblocks API, I then sign the transaction, with the following request body:

{
    "operation": "RAW",
    "externalTxId": "...",
    "assetId": "...",
    "source": {
        "type": "VAULT_ACCOUNT",
        "id": "..."
    },
    "extraParameters": {
        "rawMessageData": {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "content": "..."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


I can see the transaction in the Fireblocks UI. After the transaction is completed, I get the transaction information and signature from the fireblocks API.
This leaves me with the following response body:

{
    "id": "...",
    "assetId": "...",
    "source": {
        "id": "...",
        "type": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "subType": ""
    },
    "destination": {
        "id": null,
        "type": "UNKNOWN",
        "name": "N/A",
        "subType": ""
    },
    "requestedAmount": null,
    "amount": null,
    "netAmount": -1,
    "amountUSD": null,
    "fee": -1,
    "networkFee": -1,
    "createdAt": 1716887669163,
    "lastUpdated": 1716887791798,
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "txHash": "",
    "sourceAddress": "",
    "destinationAddress": "",
    "destinationAddressDescription": "",
    "destinationTag": "",
    "signedBy": [],
    "operation": "RAW",
    "amountInfo": {},
    "feeInfo": {},
    "signedMessages": [
        {
            "derivationPath": [
                44,
                1,
                10637,
                0,
                0
            ],
            "algorithm": "MPC_EDDSA_ED25519",
            "publicKey": "...",
            "signature": {
                "fullSig": "..."
            },
            "content": "..."
        },
    ],
    "extraParameters": {
        "rawMessageData": {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "content": "..."
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    "destinations": [],
    "externalTxId": "...",
    "blockInfo": {},
    "assetType": "BASE_ASSET"
}

Now I want to broadcast the transaction using the sendTransaction RPC method, but I'm not getting it right.
I've tried various approaches, E.G combining the unsigned transaction and the signature and I'm getting various errors, E.G Transaction signature verification failure or invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly.
How can I broadcast the transaction after signing it using Fireblocks? Are there any other steps missing in the process?
Thanks.
